# Where to put oAuth app secrets

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, oauth, openshift, credentials

I'm developing a web app which authenticates against a 3rd party service using oAuth. The 3rd party supplied me with an app secret and an app id.

The app code is supposed to live on github. Now, I don't want to push my app id and secret to github.
The app itself is supposed to be deployed on either AWS or OpenShift.

What options do these (and other) cloud computing providers offer to store credentials like that? What other options are there?

I expected them to have like a secret store, and an API to access that store from my app's code, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common options is to use environment variables (see [Openshift env vars](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html)) which you can then access within your application.

Another option is to have your config file (where you are storing the private data) listed on .gitignore and manually set it only for your Openshift app.

Comment: I like the env var approach! Haven't thought of that, yet. However, I'll wait if some more answers before selecting an answer :) Thanks, Joao!